# Problemas ao cadastrar no banco

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception, servlet

Amigos,

tenho um sistema para controlar produtividade de cada analista, sou iniciante e estou começando com JSP e SERVLET + JPA e tenho o seguinte cenario:

Estou tentando cadastrar um analista com um usuario (usario para acessar o sistema para um futuro controle de acesso) e um perfil de acesso. ja fiz as classes de DAO e Bussines para cadastrar no banco porém ao tentar cadastrar ocorre o velho e chato:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   br.com.deivsoft.controller.CadastrarAnalistaServlet.doPost(CadastrarAnalistaServlet.java:56)

Gostaria de saber se alguem pode dar uma olhada, ja tentei fazer em outros projetos e ocorre a mesma coisa, por gentileza ajude um iniciante rs desde ja agradeço segue o projeto no github.

https://github.com/deivsonbf/controle-de-produtividade-jsp-servlet

Comment: Antes desse erro ele imprime esses valores: System.out.println("equipe: "+nome); System.out.println("equipe: "+equipe);

Comment: Usei para verificar se os parâmetros estao chegando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException at br.com.deivsoft.controller.CadastrarAnalistaServlet.doPost(CadastrarAnalistaServlet.java:56)

[CadastrarAnalistaServlet.java](https://github.com/deivsonbf/controle-de-produtividade-jsp-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/deivsoft/controller/CadastrarAnalistaServlet.java)

Na linha 17 voce declara mas nao inicializa a variavel.

Durante todo o codigo ela nao e inicializada.

Diferente de variaveis primitivas, objetos sao nulos.

Na linha 56 voce chama o metodo 'salvar' da variavel que esta nula.

Para resolver seu problema voce pode, facilmente mudar a linha 17 para

`private AnalistaBusiness analistaBusiness = new AnalistaBusiness();`

Esta e uma solucao que nao esta de acordo com boas praticas, visto que isto ira gerar um uso de memoria desnecessario a cada vez que a classe for instanciada, o mais adequado seria utilizar um [framework](https://spring.io) e utilizar as annotations para criar e manipular um singleton para seu software.

Tudo isto depende, claro, da arquitetura do projeto como um todo.